# Flask blueprint cannot read sqlite3 DATABASES from config file

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, blueprint

I would like Python Flask to read from configuration file the location of the sqlite3 database name **without explicitly writing database name**. Templates used are:  http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/sqlite3/  and  http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/tutorial/dbcon/.

When I try to read 'DATABASE' from my config file I get the following error message:

File "/app/my_cool_app/app/**init**.py", line 42, in before_request
    g.db = connect_db()

File "/app/my_cool_app/app/**init**.py", line 36, in connect_db
    return sqlite3.connect(my_cool_app.config['DATABASE'])

AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'config'

Here is my **init**.py code when I try to read from the configuration file and get the above error:

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, g
from .views import my_cool_app

# create application
def create_app(debug=True):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.debug = debug
    app.config.from_object('config')
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    app.register_blueprint(my_cool_app)
    return app

def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(my_cool_app.config['DATABASE'])  <= LINE 36

@my_cool_app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = connect_db()

@my_cool_app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    db = getattr(g, 'db', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()
```

Here is my run.py (I don't change it):

```
from app import create_app
app = create_app()
```

Here is my **init**.py code that works when I explicitly write DB name (not what I want):

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, g
from .views import my_cool_app
DATABASE='/app/myappname/my_sqlite3_database_name.db'

# create application
def create_app(debug=True):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.debug = debug
    app.config.from_object('config')
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    app.register_blueprint(my_cool_app)
    return app

def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `my_cool_app` is an instance of `Blueprint` which doesn't have a `config` attribute. You need to use `current_app`:

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, g, current_app
from .views import my_cool_app

# create application
def create_app(debug=True):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.debug = debug
    app.config.from_object('config')
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    app.register_blueprint(my_cool_app)
    return app

def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(current_app.config['DATABASE'])

@my_cool_app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = connect_db()

@my_cool_app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    db = getattr(g, 'db', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Phillip Tzou!  Yes I imported the current_app and now it works as expected.